# Case-insensitive JPA unique constraint?

Tags: jpa, constraints

I'm currently using

```
@Entity
public class ... {

    /**
     * @return the loginName
     */
    @Column(unique=true)
    public String getLoginName() {
        return loginName;
    }
```

but like to have a case-insensitive constraint such that a login name "UPPERCASE" is not allowed when there is already a login name "uppercase" in the database. Is there anything I can use or do I have to create the dirty workaround of storing a lower case version in a separate column?

Comment: Whad database are you using? PostgreSQL or other?

Comment: I don't want to make it dependent on the database.

Answer (score 5):

This is not something covered by JPA, and I'd say not even implementations (e.g. Hibernate).

One thing you can do is create a [`@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` handler](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/listeners.html) that will fill another (additional) entity field with normalized (lowercase) value, and have the constraint on that.

```
@Entity Foo { 
    private value;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private valueLowercased;

    @PrePersist @PreUpdate private prepare(){
        this.valueLowercased = value == null ? null : value.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Non-JPA approach could be to have an additional column `myColumnLowercased` with an `UNIQUE INDEX` and a trigger that would set the value to `LOWERCASE(new.myColumn)`.  (Nomenclature may differ across databases.)

Some [databases support "functional indexes"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-expressional.html) which is you can index by an expression.

```
CREATE INDEX test1_lower_col1_idx ON test1 (lower(col1));
```

Comment: I wonder if this might, in some cases at least, break equals() and hashcode() contracts on the Foo class?  If it's required that value be case-insensitively unique, maybe equals and hc need to reflect that, in which case having the lower-cased value populated prepersist and preupdate is too late (cf id)?

Comment: @Ian I think your question is mixing layers / concepts. If you create an in-memory object which was not validated against entities existing in the database, then surely it will exist in-memory and have non-unique ID. That's hardly something you can handle in equals/hashCode.

If we are talking just about comparing two in-memory objects, then it's up to definition of the entity whether ID of "foo" equals the ID of "FOO", and is a different aspect, IMO. But yes, its' related.