# How to add a case insensitive JPA unique constraint?

Tags: jpa, case-insensitive

I want to add a case insensitive unique constraint to a JPA entity.

Assume we have an entity employee which needs to have unique constraint for two columns `NAME` and `PROJECT_TITLE` where `NAME` is case insensitive.

Insertion of `JoHn`, `PROJECT1` should cause unique constraint violation when a row `JOHN,PROJECT1` already exists in database as `JOHN`, `JoHn` are same in our case.

The SQL for the above requirement is given below

```
ALTER TABLE employee ADD CONSTRAINT employee_name_unique
    UNIQUE(LOWER(NAME),PROJECT_TITLE);
```

Comment: SQL is the right tool for the job. Use it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031709/hibernate-annotations-case-insensitive-uniqueconstraint

Answer (score 5):

JPA doesn't support this kind of constraints. For a pure JPA solution, you'll have to use additional column. See the answer here: [Case-insensitive JPA unique constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645618/case-insensitive-jpa-unique-constraint/42213413#42213485)

```
@Entity Foo { 
    private value;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private valueLowercased;

    @PrePersist @PreUpdate private prepare(){
        this.valueLowercased = value == null ? null : value.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like JPA to support a case insensitive uniqueness constraint and made a feature request here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jpa-api/issues/209